# How to add object in "proxy" in package.json using CRA?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I updated the version, and now I can no longer add objects. I also followed the documentation saying to create "setupProxy.js" inside "src", but when I do that, the application just doesn't run and displays a message saying "Unexpected identifier".

What I want to keep using:

```
"proxy": {
  "/api": "http://dev.siga.avenida.com.br:8686"
},
```

Is there any way to get the same result by turning it into string?

What I tried to do and that raises an error:

```
// src/setupProxy.js
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';
export default function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api/', {target: 'http://dev.siga.avenida.com.br:8686'}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually) they mentioned.

> Note: This file only supports Node's JavaScript syntax. Be sure to only use supported language features (i.e. no support for Flow, ES Modules, etc).

So `import`, `export` throws syntax error, while node.js environment doesn't support it. And it seems this is the case for you.

You need to use `CommonJS` module system which is default in nodejs.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://dev.siga.avenida.com.br:8686' }));
};
```